# Problem with taxonomy menu in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, nodes

I have a problem with the module "Taxonomy Menu" in Drupal 7.
I have a menu where the parent element is "Categories" and children are all Taxonomies (is located on "Main Menu")

When I create content, choose your taxonomy and save. This taxonomy was selected, it appears as menu in the "main menu" of my drupal site. That is, it escapes the parent element that contains it.

Is this configurable module itself? (I do not see a configuration related to that) or is it a problem in the module?

Comment: the configuration of taxonomy menu apear in the vocabulary page .

Comment: But the same issue exist.. The term child escapes of the term parent in drupal 7 :(